# Serilog, Change the loglevel at runtime for a specific namespace (> MinimumLevel)

Tags: serilog

This is my default Serilog configuration

```
SeriLogLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(SeriLogLevelSwitch)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     ....
```

How can i change the loglevel to Debug for a specific namespace at runtime when the default is Information?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each of your `MinimumLevel.Override` can have its own `LoggingLevelSwitch`, which allows you to control the log level for each particular override at run-time.

Create individual `LoggingLevelSwitch` for each override that you intend to modify whilst the app is running, and store these instances in a place that you can access from other parts of your application, which will allow you to change the `MinimumLevel` of these `LoggingLevelSwitch`(es).

e.g.

```
public class LoggingLevelSwitches
{
    // Logging level switch that will be used for the "Microsoft" namespace
    public static readonly LoggingLevelSwitch MicrosoftLevelSwitch
        = new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Warning);

    // Logging level switch that will be used for the "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" namespace
    public static readonly LoggingLevelSwitch MicrosoftHostingLifetimeLevelSwitch
        = new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Information);
}
```

Configure your Serilog logging pipeline to use these `LoggingLevelSwitch` instances:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LoggingLevelSwitches.MicrosoftLevelSwitch)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime",
            LoggingLevelSwitches.MicrosoftHostingLifetimeLevelSwitch)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .CreateLogger();

    // ...
}
```

Then somewhere in your application, for example, in the code that handles your application configuration that can be changed at run-time, update the `LoggingLevelSwitch` instance(s) to the new `LogEventLevel` that you want:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    void ChangeLoggingEventLevel()
    {
        LoggingLevelSwitches.MicrosoftHostingLifetimeLevelSwitch
            .MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;

        LoggingLevelSwitches.MicrosoftHostingLifetimeLevelSwitch
            .MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, the `LogEventLevel` is controlled by the `LoggingLevelSwitch` instances, so it's up to you to decide where in your application (and how) these instances will be modified, to affect the logging pipeline.

The example above I'm assuming you have a screen (or API) in your application that a user would be able to configure the logging levels.

If you don't have that, then another approach is to have a background thread that periodically checks a configuration file, an environment variable, or query a database, etc. to determine what these logging levels should be.

If you're using a .NET Core Host, you can use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which can handle the refresh of the configuration for you, and allow you to execute code when the configuration changes (where you'd change the `MinimumLevel` of your `LoggingLevelSwitch`(es) you have.

Comment: it appears the library doesn't really support what I want, but this answer comes closest to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an **environment variable** paired with another `MinimumLevel.Override` to change the loglevel to `Debug` for a specific namespace at runtime like so:

```
using System;

...

SeriLogLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(SeriLogLevelSwitch)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .MinimumLevel.Override(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SPECIFIC_NAMESPACE"), LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     ....
```

Then, ensure the environment variable `SPECIFIC_NAMESPACE` is accessible by your application at runtime. Note that "namespace" is synonymous with "source context prefix"

[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: This looks like a variation on the startup-time code. Are you sure it's really runtime?

Comment: Code that runs when an application starts (startup-time) is also part of runtime. The distinction of the times is only between run-time and compile-time.  With the example from my answer, you can configure your logger dynamically when you run your application

Comment: I agree with @richytong and this was exactly what I've been looking for.+1