# How to check current log level using ILogger?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, coreclr, microsoft.extensions.logging

I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`. I want to log request object only when LogLevel is set to `Information`

I know I can log the request object as

```
_logger.LogInformation("{request}", request);
```

I am using `Serilog` as logger. This serializes the object and logs request as json string as expected. But I don't know if Logging framework checks the log level first and then serializes or always serializes first and then check for log level. Because I don't want to serialize the object on every call if LogLevel is set to higher than Information.

Is there anyway to check LogLevel using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`

```
    private Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<RoutesController> _logger = null;

    public RoutesController(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<RoutesController> logger)
    {            
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public void Route([FromBody]JObject request)
    {
       //how to check current LogLevel here?
        if(_logger.LogLevel == "Information")
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.Serialize(request));
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get the current LogLevel of an ILogger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074122/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-loglevel-of-an-ilogger)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [`IsEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.logger-1.microsoft-extensions-logging-ilogger-isenabled?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method of `ILogger<T>`

```
if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information)
{
    //... 
}
```

Another alternative is to use a [`LoggingLevelSwitch`](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/10/dynamically-changing-the-serilog-level/) to control the minimum level and make it accessible to your code, so that you can perform the check at a later time.

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LoggingLevelSwitches.GlobalLevelSwitch)
  .WriteTo.Console()
  .CreateLogger();

public class LoggingLevelSwitches
{
    public static readonly LoggingLevelSwitch GlobalLevelSwitch
        = new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Information);
}

public void Route([FromBody]JObject request)
{
    // (example... You prob. would check for >= Information)
    if (LoggingLevelSwitches.GlobalLevelSwitch.MinimumLevel == LogEventLevel.Information)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.Serialize(request));
    }           
}
```

You can also use multiple `LoggingLevelSwitch` instances for individual sinks (usually an argument called `restrictedToMinimumLevel`). See [Serilog, Change the loglevel at runtime for a specific namespace (> MinimumLevel)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62074296).